How to configure Envoy gateway to work with https
I am trying to setup an TLS terminated HTTPRoute using envoy-gateway. I have configured the GatewayClass that looks like:
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: GatewayClass
metadata:
  name: https
spec:
  controllerName: gateway.envoyproxy.io/gatewayclass-controller
  parametersRef:
    group: gateway.envoyproxy.io
    kind: EnvoyProxy
    name: custom-proxy-config
    namespace: envoy-gateway-system

an EnvoyProxy object to do some controlling on the pod and also add the required annotation for the Loadbalancer service:
apiVersion: gateway.envoyproxy.io/v1alpha1
kind: EnvoyProxy
metadata:
  name: custom-proxy-config
  namespace: envoy-gateway-system
spec:
  provider:
    type: Kubernetes
    kubernetes:
      envoyDeployment:
        pod:
          annotations:
            annotation:1
        container:
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 150m
              memory: 640Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 1Gi
      envoyHpa:
        minReplicas: 2
        maxReplicas: 10
        metrics:
          - resource:
              name: cpu
              target:
                averageUtilization: 60
                type: Utilization
            type: Resource

The gateway that looks like this:
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: shared-gateway
  namespace: envoy-gateway-system
spec:
  gatewayClassName: https
  listeners:
  - name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
    port: 443
    allowedRoutes:
      namespaces:
        from: Selector
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            shared-gateway-access: "true"
    tls:
      certificateRefs:
      - name: ssl
        kind: Secret

The secret is generated by certmanager and it is a valid certificate.
It starts the LoadBalancer service just fine it also have the externalIP configured. But in the newly created envoy-gateway-* pod logs I see the following:
[2024-10-05 08:02:30.190][1][warning][misc] [source/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/config.cc:83] internal_address_config is not configured. The existing default behaviour will trust RFC1918 IP addresses, but this will be changed in next release. Please explictily config internal address config as the migration step.

